# For loop using dates Compile Error: Syntax Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a script that will skim through all rows for a certain column. Then it will compare the dates in these columns with a set date. If the dates is larger than it deletes the row. The error I'm getting is called Compile Error: Syntax Error.

```
Sub removewrongyear()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 635475
 If Data.Cells(i,20).Value > DATE(2018,12,31) Then
Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You will want to step backwards when deleting rows.

Comment: What is `YearA`?

Comment: What you're trying to do is better accomplished by autofilter.

Comment: @JohnyL Sorry Year A is the current year I determine in another part of script I will edit it to 2018 to not confuse.

Comment: OK. Then, what is `Data`? Programmatic sheet name?

Comment: @JohnyL yes Data is another sheet I am referencing in the woorkbook

Comment: Also that's going to take a long time with 600k rows. Perhaps try autofilter or arrays.

Comment: `Integer` is stored across 16 bits. One of these bits controls the sign, so the maximum positive value is `2^15-1`, or 32,767. Anything greater than that needs to be a `Long`, stored on 32 bits, with a max value of `2^31-1`.

Comment: I will add code to perform row removal much faster as a 2nd option in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yuo need to step backwards as @braX stated. Also specified number exceeds `Integer` variable type capacity. In VBA it is a good practice for ingeter values to always declare variable as `Long`.

Range "Data" is nowhere set. I replaced it with reference to active worksheet.
Variable YearA is also not specified. I assigned value of 2018 to it. Date function is incorrectly used, you meant to use DateSerial.

Always put `Option Explicit` on top of the code to catch errors. There were really many here.

```
Option Explicit

Sub removeWrongYear()

    Dim i As Long, yearA as Long

    yearA = 2018

    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 635475 to 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(i,20).Value > DateSerial(yearA,12,31) Then .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete       
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Here is a fast version, based on arrays, with all rows deleted at once:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1 'row and column index will match array index

Sub removeWrongYear()

    Dim i As Long, yearA As Long, rowsCnt As Long
    Dim rowsToDelete As Range
    Dim vData As Variant

    yearA = 2018

    With ActiveSheet

        '1st to 635475 row, 20th column
        vData = Range(.Cells(1, 20), .Cells(635475, 20))

        For i = UBound(vData) To 2 Step -1
            If vData(i, 1) > DateSerial(yearA, 12, 31) Then
                rowsCnt = rowsCnt + 1

                If rowsCnt > 1 Then
                    Set rowsToDelete = Union(rowsToDelete, .Rows(i))
                ElseIf rowsCnt = 1 Then
                    Set rowsToDelete = .Rows(i)
                End If

            End If
        Next i

    End With

    If rowsCnt > 0 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        rowsToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I am having an issue with comparing the dates as their format is different one is formatted as 27-JAN-18 and the other is 2017-12-31. Is there a way to convert these dates.

Comment: You can put a break point near date comparison and see how format of compared dates looks like by hovering over. Normally in VBA everything what is date is comparable, because it represents `Long` value. Problem can arise when VBA does not recognize cell contents as date, but `String`. In such case depending on actual `String`, dedicated code should be written to convert it to `Date`.